# Attach Froogaloop event to Flexslider current slide

Tags: jquery, api, vimeo, flexslider, froogaloop

I am building a slider with multiple Vimeo videos using Woo Theme's Flexslider. I am able to get the Flexslider to play and pause based on the vimeo events, using their Froogaloop ($f) library, however I cannot get the next/previous events in Flexslider to pause the video.

It works if each vimeo player is hardcoded as a variable, however I need the slider to be able to support any number of videos. See an example here: http://demo.astronautweb.co/slider/flex/vimeo-multi.html

The example on the [Flexslider page](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/video.html) hooks the slider event with `$f(player)` which is an object (I think). This only targets the **last** slide when I use it in my code. W

When I try to use Flexslider's own **slide.currentSlide**, I can only target an element, not an object. This is where I have reach the upper limits of my javascript knowledge.

Here's the code:

```
$(window).load(function(){  

var vimeoPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('iframe'),
    player;

for (var i = 0, length = vimeoPlayers.length; i < length; i++) {
    player = vimeoPlayers[i];
    $f(player).addEvent('ready', ready);
}

function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
    (element.addEventListener) ? element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false) : element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false);
}

function ready(player_id) {
    var froogaloop = $f(player_id);

    froogaloop.addEvent('play', function(data) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider("pause");
    });

    froogaloop.addEvent('pause', function(data) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider("play");
    });
}

var slider = $(".flexslider");

slider.flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    video: true, 
    start: function(slider){
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
    },
    before: function(slider){ 

        // this only pauses the last slide
        $f(player).api('pause');

        // this is the Flexslider API for targeting the current slide
        var currentSlide = slider.slides.eq(slider.currentSlide + 1),
            currentFrame = currentSlide.find('iframe');

        console.log(currentFrame);  
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your example on astronautweb.co it looks like you're using an older version of the Froogaloop API. Grabbing the latest should make this a lot easier https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript

```
// Enable the API on each Vimeo video
    $('iframe.vimeo-player').each(function(){
  $f(this).addEvent('ready');
});

// Call fitVid before FlexSlider initializes, so the proper initial height can be retrieved.
$(".flexslider")
    .fitVids()
  .flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshow: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    smoothHeight: true,
    start: function(slider) {
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    },
    before: function(slider) {

      currentSlide = slider.currentSlide;
      player_id = currentSlide + 1
      currentVideo = 'player_' + player_id;

      $f(currentVideo).api('pause');

    }
});
```

Here's another [example of the Froogaloop API 2.0](http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/vimeo/froogaloop2-api-basics.html)